# Qt5 [make -snap] doesn't compile properly: The process "/usr/bin/snap" exited with code 1

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5, qt-creator

I copied/paste a `Qt5` project folder from a computer to another computer. They are both `Ubuntu 18.04`.

Same version of `Qt5` and same libraries/dependencies. On the new computer, I have `CMake 3.10.2`, but I don't remember the verion of `CMake` I had on the former one. (Probably `CMake 3.8`).

As soon as I open `Qt5` and open the folder containing the `CMakeLists.txt` file, and click on it, I get the following result from the output:

```
08:02:22: Running steps for project newcam-proc...     
08:02:22: Persisting CMake state...  
08:02:22: Starting: "/usr/bin/snap" --build . --target all error: unknown flag `build' 
08:02:22: The process "/usr/bin/snap" exited with code 1. 
Error while building/deploying project myProject (kit: Desktop Qt 5.12.5 GCC 64bit) 
The kit Desktop Qt 5.12.5 GCC 64bit has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem. When executing step "CMake Build" 
08:02:22: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

And below the `General Message` I get:

```
Project ERROR: You need to set the ANDROID_NDK_ROOT environment variable to point to your Android NDK.
Could not read qmake configuration file /home/emanuele/Qt/5.12.5/android_armv7/mkspecs/android-clang/qmake.conf.
Project ERROR: You need to set the ANDROID_NDK_ROOT environment variable to point to your Android NDK.
Could not read qmake configuration file /home/emanuele/Qt/5.12.5/android_x86/mkspecs/android-clang/qmake.conf.
Running /usr/bin/snap /home/emanuele/Desktop/myProject -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=/usr/bin/g++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING=/home/emanuele/Qt/5.12.5/gcc_64 -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:STRING=/home/emanuele/Qt/5.12.5/gcc_64/bin/qmake in /tmp/QtCreator-vlHbHY/qtc-cmake-LvUefYdh.
error: unknown command "/home/emanuele/Desktop/myProject", see 'snap help'.
CMake process exited with exit code 1.
```

I never had to use `Android NDK` on my previous project, nor I had to install it. And I am not sure why on the new machine is showing this message.

In addition it seems that is trying to use `snap` instead of the usual `make`.

I am not sure about what is happening and why.

**What I tried so far:**

1) The only thing that came to my mind was to try to create a small example application and see if it runs, it actually runs properly and gives no error as shown below:

```
08:16:00: Running steps for project untitled...
08:16:00: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
08:16:00: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" -j8
make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
08:16:00: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
08:16:00: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

It seems that the project that I copied/paste uses `snap` and if I create a new project, like a `Qt Widget application`, it actually uses `make`, exiting correctly in the output.

Comment: @squareskittles, thanks for reading my question. I see what the problem is. Thanks for the advise, the problem is solved. If you post your answer I can mark it as correct :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flags `--build . --target all` are flags you typically see passed to the `cmake` executable, not the `snap` executable. This hints that your CMake environment is not configured correctly in the IDE on your new machine. I suggest following the QtCreator CMake setup instructions [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-cmake.html#adding-cmake-tools) to help get it configured:

> To specify paths to CMake executables:
>
> 1. Select **Tools** > **Options** > **Kits** > **CMake** > **Add**.
> 2. In the **Name** field, specify a name for the tool.
> 3. In the **Path** field, specify the path to the CMake executable.
> 4. Select the **Auto-create build directories** check box to automatically create build directories for CMake projects.
> 5. Select **Apply** to save your changes.

Comment: This still happens to me even tho cmake is configured correctly, I've installed cmake via snap and the kit is using the cmake found in: "/snap/bin/cmake". But when I look at the build command I see this: "snap --build . --target all"

Comment: Very annoying but can be resolved by using normal apt-get *sigh*. Just remove it from snap and then run the command: sudo apt-get install cmake

Answer (score 0):

After installing Qt, I wanted to create a new Qt Widgets project application, and then I found that when I selected CMake, I got an error:

```
Project ERROR: You need to set the ANDROID_NDK_ROOT environment variable to point to your Android NDK.
Could not read qmake configuration file/opt/QT5.14.2 5.14.2 / android/mkspecs/android - clang/qmake. Conf.... see 'snap help'.
```

I was confused as to why I was prompted to need `snap help`. Then I checked *`Tools > Options > Kits > CMake`* and found that my CMake was installed via Snap. Then I manually downloaded and installed CMake again.

After removing CMake through `sudo snap`, I found that it could be compiled normally.

I think Snap installed CMake should not be used with Qt.